# Filling color on image with python

Tags: python, image, drawing, fill, bucket

Lets say I have some image that just have some shapes on white background

with knowing some x,y point I want to fill it with by replacing white inside the shape (if x,y is inside the shape)

Basically like image editors do it with paint bucket tool

[image]

is there something built-in ? if not - what coulbe the algorithm name for such case ?

Comment: What are you using to draw the image?

Comment: image comes from users (no programatic draw)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seems a PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill can do the trick